# Renaming the product tab-title for WooCommerce Version 2.6.13

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs

I am using WooCommerce Version 2.6.13 because the latest version of WooCommerce is not supporting my theme. I need to rename the product tab and tried to use the following snippet to rename tabs. But it does not work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 98 );
function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) {
$tabs['description']['title'] = __( 'تفاصيل' );     // Rename the description tab
return $tabs;
}
```

tabs.php

```
<?php
/**
* Single Product tabs
*
* @author   WooThemes
* @package  WooCommerce/Templates
* @version  2.4.0
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

/**
* Filter tabs and allow third parties to add their own
*
* Each tab is an array containing title, callback and priority.
* @see woocommerce_default_product_tabs()
*/
$tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );

if ( empty($tabs) ) {
 return;
}
$tab_keys = array_keys( $tabs );
$active_tab_key = array_shift( $tab_keys );
?>
<div id="shopreviews" class="tours-tabs">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) {
    printf( '<li%s><a href="#tab%s" data-toggle="tab">%s</a></li>',
        $key == $active_tab_key ? ' class="active"' : '',
        $key,
        apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_' . $key . '_tab_title', $tab['title'], $key )
    );
}; ?>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) {
        if ( empty( $tab['content'] ) && ! empty( $tab['callback'] ) ) { 
            ob_start();
            call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab );
            $tab['content'] = ob_get_clean();
        }

        printf(
            '<div class="tab-pane %s" id="tab%s">' . 
                '<div class="tours-tabs__content padding-all">%s</div>' .
            '</div>',
            $key == $active_tab_key ? 'in active' : 'fade',
            $key,
            $tab['content']
        );
    } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my page http://royalfalconholidays.com/arabic/tours/exotic/ and I have to rename the the title 'Details' to arabic.
Any suggestions? Perhaps there is a different/better method ?

Comment: Check this path: `wp-content/themes/adventure-tours/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/tabs.php` - does it exist? If so, add its code to your question. If not, add `var_dump( $tabs );` to the `woo_rename_tabs()` function (before the `return` line), and add its output to your question. You can also try changing the hook's priority from `98` to `198` or a higher value.

Comment: Hi , I updated the question with tabs.php

Comment: Thank you for the update. Try changing `add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 98 );` to `add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 198 );` and check the title of the corresponding tab. Do you see the title you want?

Comment: I tried but still it showing nothing

Comment: Ok, please revert the changes you've made. Now change `function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) {` to `function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) { echo 'var_dump() output: <pre>'; var_dump($tabs); echo '</pre>';`, visit the page, and then add the `var_dump()` output to your question.

Comment: Can you confirm  I have to add like this below ?
` add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 98 );
function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) { echo 'var_dump() output: <pre>'; var_dump($tabs); echo '</pre>'
$tabs['description']['title'] = __( 'تفاصيل' );     // Rename the description tab
return $tabs;
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174928/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-ub-303).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this snippet doesn't work for you:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 98 );
function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) {
$tabs['description']['title'] = __( 'تفاصيل' );     // Rename the description tab
return $tabs;
}
```

But there's another filter you can use (which [you've already tried](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174928/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-ub-303)..): `woocommerce_product_description_tab_title`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_description_tab_title', function(){
    return 'تفاصيل';
} );
```

---

And if you want to change the title of the *other tabs*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_photos_tab_title', function(){
    return 'Title for the "photos" tab';
} );
```

So just substitute `description` with the tab's *key* — e.g. `photos` for the "Photos" tab.